# How to reinstall latest Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I've followed the instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install, first doing the steps that lead to phablet-flash -b and then the manual ones. In both cases, I get stuck at the Google boot screen. It does not boot into Touch. No errors during manual install, and adb devices shows the device, but I get the following with phablet-flash or phablet-flash -b (second and subsequent times, not the first time):

```
Device detected as /system/bin/sh: getprop: not found 
Unsupported device, autodetect fails device
When working on flipped images, detection does not work and would require -d
```

Not clear what that all means.

The Nexus 4 had the initial Touch dev preview on it, FYI. I saw no separate instructions for upgrading from that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the codename `phablet-flash -d mako -b`

Comment: Thanks -- that installed it! It loaded the same file as previous attempts, but whatever! Not booting into Touch though, still stuck at Google screen.

Comment: Ran the install a second time, and now it boots into Touch. I guess there were more cobwebs to be cleared in memory :)

Comment: It hangs for me on the -bootstap switch sometimes. :)

Comment: @GalenGruman Can you mark this as answered, then?